# Formatting Rspec to remove extra spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a not-so-big monitor. When I run tests on Rspec via Spring there's a lot of spaces/lines. Something like this:

[image]

How do I remove the extra lines? I'd also like to remove the "randomzied with seed" line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to run tests with Spring but, using `grep` you can filter the output of any command. Open a terminal and execute this command:

```
your_spring_command_to_run_tests | grep -v -e '^$' -e 'Randomzied'
```

Doing that you will remove **empty lines** and rows with the word **Randomized** in it.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to brother Chelemsky's post: https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Custom-Formatters

OR

http://codingdaily.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/write-your-own-custom-rspec-formatter/